# Most efficient way to get a Users Tags

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a somewhat complicated database structure in a Ruby on Rails project. A **User** can have many **EmailAccounts**, an **EmailAccount** can have many **Subscriptions** (many-to-many via a join table), and a **Subscription** can have many **Tags** (also many-to-many)

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "first_name"
t.string   "last_name"
t.date     "dob"
t.string   "gender"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "email_accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "user_id"
t.string   "email"
t.string   "provider"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "account_subscriptions", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "email_account_id", null: false
t.integer  "subscription_id",  null: false
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "subscriptions", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "email"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "domain"
end

create_table "sub_tags", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "subscription_id", null: false
t.integer  "tag_id",          null: false
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

I want to see which **Tags** apply to a **User** through this relationship. Whats the most efficient way to do so (eager load all the relationships and loop through them, do a multi-level join in Postgres, etc)?

Comment: Is that email column in 'subscriptions' table same as the one in 'email_accounts'?

Comment: Better if you show the schema in an image with relationships!

Comment: @amit_saxena Nope, 'email_accounts' email are personal emails (ex: someone@gmail.com) and a 'subscriptions' are ones you'd receive from a newsletter (ex: updates@amazon.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the right models

```
user = User.find(user_id)
tags = Tag.where(:id => SubTag.where(:subscription_id => AccountSubscription.where(:email_account_id => user.email_accounts.map{|e| e.id}).map{|a_s| a_s.subscription_id}).map{|s_t| s_t.tag_id})
tag_name = tags.map{|t| t.name}
```

this should work fine given you have the right indexes.

Comment: Pretty close but this will return a list of all the SubTags, which are a join table. I want the tags themselves (also there shouldn't be a 's' at the end of 'SubTag'